# Issue adding BaseGameUtils to libgdx project

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play, google-play-services

UPD: I solved the problem by changing usage of GameHelper constructor from

```
gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
```

to

```
gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
```

But I don't know why it helped. So I would be happy if someone explain it to me)

I am having issue adding baseGameUtils to my libGDX project. Gradle linking works fine, but when I running the game, apk building fails. Gradle console message:

```
Executing tasks: [:android:assembleDebug]  

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:android:checkDebugManifest  
:android:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE  
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE  
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE  
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE  
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:compileLint  
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE  
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:preBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE  
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:checkReleaseManifest
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:prepareReleaseDependencies
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:libraries:BaseGameUtils:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6587Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareTestLibrariesBaseGameUtils10Library UP-TO-DATE
:android:prepareDebugDependencies
:android:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE  
:android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE  
:android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:android:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE  
:android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:android:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE  
:android:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:android:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE  
:android:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE  
:android:compileDebugJava  
:android:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE  
:android:compileDebugSources  
:android:preDexDebug  
:android:dexDebug  
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","position":{},"original":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:282)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:282)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)"}


FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

   What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

   Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I found that if I comment the compiling of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 library in build.gradle of BaseGameUtils than game works fine, but I get a crash when I try to login to google-play from game. It could be mistake in my code, but excluding dependancy appcompat-v7 from BaseGameUtils just can't be right. What should I do to build my game with it?

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 22
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.game.android/com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
}
```

Here is what logcat shows on failed login attempt:

> 09-12 01:26:21.084  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: resetting attempt count.
>   09-12 01:26:21.084  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Starting USER-INITIATED sign-in flow.
>   09-12 01:26:21.084  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: beginUserInitiatedSignIn: starting new sign-in flow.
>   09-12 01:26:21.084  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android D/GameHelper﹕ GameHelper: Starting connection.
>   09-12 01:26:21.184  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   09-12 01:26:21.184  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0cfcb20)
>   09-12 01:26:21.184  15670-15670/ru.zuko.game.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: ru.zuko.game.android, PID: 15670
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.b(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$h.g(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$b.hy(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.internal.jl$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are adding BaseGameUtils to your project but best way to add that works for me is copy paste the whole package from BaseGameUtils to your game-android project. You can than reference your Helper classes from your own project.[GameHelper, GameHelperUtils] No need of adding a different project as dependency just for 2 java files. You can also delete useless activity code if you want.

Also use play service in gradle dependency instead of adding as library just in case you are not doing this already.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Maybe you are right, because I was forsed to exclude play services from my gradle.build of android, because it is already included in BaseGameUtils's gradle.build. But Google tutorial sais that it isn't right to include only part of BaseGameUtils. I'll try to do it your way.

Comment: This did no help, I got the same error when I included just src files

Comment: Here is an example how you should do. https://github.com/piotr-j/Super-Flying-Gentlemen/